# jQuery getting all elements that do not have an id assigned

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of divs inside a parent div, some of which have an ID, others do not (on purpose), but they all have the same class. How can I get a list of just the divs that do not have an id assigned?

```
<div class='AllQuestions'>
    <div class='questionList'>Something Something</div>
    <div class='questionList'>Something Something</div>        
    <div class='questionList' id='question-20'>Something Something</div>
    <div class='questionList' id='question-22'>Something Something</div>        
    <div class='questionList'>Something Something</div>
    <div class='questionList' id='question-100'>Something Something</div>
</div>
```

I know I can do `$('.questionList')` to get a list of all the divs, but I do not know a way to filter out the ones with an id. (also, id's can not be reliably predicted as I am generating them randomly)

Maybe one approach is to somehow remove the ones with an id?

Comment: Have you looked at the jQuery selectors documentation? http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: yes, but it didn't really help me with "not id" since I'm not very experienced with them. I pretty much know the basics of id and class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your list, then exclude those with an id attribute:

```
$('.questionList').not('[id]')
```

Note that this should be faster than putting it all in one selector due to the jQuery sizzle right to left selector - and to me is simpler to view/understand.

Comment: I think this one was what was easiest for me to implement, but all the answers were great. This does work a little faster for my large list.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `$('.AllQuestions .questionList:not([id])')`. That should work fine.

Check out these links:

- [not selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)
- [has attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)

Comment: awesome answer, very direct, didn't know i could select two classes at once.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var list = $(".questionList:not([id])");
```

Comment: awesome answer, this works as well. And I like that the not is on the inside of the selector.